# Opening a file without extension

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem opening a file in C#.
I got a file which I need to read and when I'm trying to open it using C#, for some reason file cannot be found.
Here is my code:

```
 string fullpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + 
                   string.Format(@"\FT933\FT33_1");
 try
 {
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullpath);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
       Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
 }
```

The file I'm trying to open is inside `Debug\FT933\FT33_1` and got no extension.
Whenever I'm trying to open a text file from the same directory I manage to do so.

```
EDIT:
```

to be more it precise i think that problem that i have is that i dont know how to open a file that has no extentions (if i change the file to have .txt extention i do manage to open it)

Comment: it has no extention when i push properties its says the file type is file

Comment: When building paths, use `Path.Combine` instead of concatenation.

Comment: if you debug, what is the value of fullpath before you pass it to the StreamReader? It might not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: AH - what is the error message? You expect us to wildly guess?

Comment: You need to close your StreamReader

Comment: "C:\\Users\\Stern\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Engine\\ConsoleApplication1\\bin\\Debug\\FT933\\FT33_1" this is the full path

Comment: @NadavStern - That is the output when debugging? If you copy this path to the windows explorer, does it actually find a file there or not? It should not matter if the file has an extension or not.

Comment: it doesnt work , i mean when i paste it to windows explorer it gives me an error says that i should look for spelling mistakes which i dont have

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use hardcoded path or directories, but builtin functions to join paths.
Try

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string fullpath = Path.Combine(path, your_filename);
```

And remember that current directory could not be your app's one!.
More, always include streams in `using` statement

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullpath))
{
    // Do here what you need
}
```

so you're sure it will be released when necessary not wasting memory!

**EDITED after OP comment:**
This is my working attempt:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string fullpath = Path.Combine(path, @"FT933\FT33_1");
if (File.Exists(fullpath))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullpath))
    {
        string ret = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
else
{
    // File does not exists
}
```

If you fall in `// File does not exists` section, be sure that file is not where you're searching for!
Are you sure your file does not have an hidden extension?
Are you sure OS or some app is not locking file for some reason?

**EDITED again after another comment:**
Open a command prompt (using Start->Run->CMD (enter) ) and run this command:

```
dir "C:\Users\Stern\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Engine\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\FT933\*.*" /s
```

and edit your question showing us result.

Comment: the problem that i have is with openning a file with no extention my file type is file if the file had txt extention i wouldnt have this kind of problem.

Comment: @NadavStern: are you sure that file has not any extension? Maybe it's hidden from OS. Or maybe that file is locked from OS...

Comment: the file type is file 100% sure

Comment: @NadavStern: believe me, I've just tried and it works for me. See my edited post in a minute.

Comment: @NadavStern: you have to write `using System.IO;` for Path and `using System.Reflection;` for Assembly.

Comment: it doesnt work , same as before probably the extension is the problem

Comment: @NadavStern: NO, no, no, it's not the extension!! I've already told you taht I used the code I showed you succesfully on a file that has same name of yours! It's something else! Try my edited code in a minute and let me know

Comment: @NadavStern: your file does not exist there, this is my answer. Or you don't have rights to access it, or OS is locking it, I don't know. But if `File.Exists()` is false, that file is not in the place you're searching for, I'm sorry ;)

Comment: @NadavStern: did you try what I told you?